# How to get HTML 5 input type=“date” working in Firefox

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, firefox, datepicker

I find it odd that input type="date" is still not supported in Firefox after all of this time. In fact, I don't think they added in much (if any) of the HTML 5 new types on an input element. Not surprised that it is not supported in IE10. So, my question is...

How to get type="date" on an input element working without adding, yet another, .js file (namely jQueryUI DatePicker Widget) just to get a calendar/date for only IE and Firefox Browsers? Is there something out there that can be applied somewhere (CDN perhaps?) that will make this functionality work by default in Firefox and/or IE Browsers?? Trying to target IE 8+ Browsers and for Firefox, doesn't matter, newest version (28.0) will be fine.

UPDATE: Firefox 57+ supports input type=date

Comment: If the browser does not support it, then the browser does not support it! You need to use a jQuery datepicker plugin

Answer (score 0):

if you are already using jquery then you can simply add date picker by

```
<input name="startDate" id="startDate" class="date-picker" />
```

and you can use jquery if you are not using it by adding this line without downloading any file

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

and the script on the page ready will be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.date-picker').datepicker( {
         autoclose: true,
         todayHighlight: true,
    });
});
```

Comment: `jquery.js` does not include a datepicker!

Comment: Well that would not work since you have the scripts in the wrong order. but more importantly OP has stated _without adding, yet another, .js file (namely jQueryUI DatePicker)_

Comment: OP has also asked for cdn

Comment: i think the op don't want to download the file and manually add it.
well then cdn can help the OP

Answer (score 0):

Try to use date picker plugin. Since firefox doesn't support HTML5 date input. Or else in Firefox you can activate it in about:config by enabling dom.forms.datetype option.